# string replace text with PHP

Tags: php

I have

```
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive';
```

i want to replace --ACT-- and --INA-- with value i did:

```
str_replace(array('--ACT--','--INA--'), array('<div class="wp"><b>1</b></div>','<div class="wp"><b>2</b></div>'), $text);
```

results is

```
<div class="wp"><b>1</b></div> Active
<div class="wp"><b>2</b></div> inactive
```

but I want to add **active** and **inactive** text inside div not outside div like:

```
<div class="wp"><b>1</b> active</div>
```

i don't want to add this text in str_replace, i want to get it from $text variable, any help?

Comment: Then replace the whole thing: `str_replace('--ACT-- active', '<div class="wp"><b>1</b> Active</div>', $text);` (but with an array to cover both, like you're already doing).

Comment: No, as i said i don't want to add this text in str_replace, i want to get it from $text variable, any way?

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to do it in the easiest and most obvious way? If you give us a hint why and what it is you're trying to solve, it's easier for us to come up with a proper suggestion.

Comment: In that case you need regex preg_replace

Comment: @Andreas how please? is there a way to do it without preg_replace i want str_replace

Comment: Impossible. I can post an preg_replace. But str_replace is impossible or at least extremely hard

Comment: ok how with preg_replace?

Answer (score 3):

Use preg_replace and capture the word after the ACT/INA and place html around it.

```
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive';

// Add html to active
$text = preg_replace("/--ACT-- (\w+)/" , '<div class="wp"><b>1</b>$1</div>',$text);

// Add html to inactive and echo
Echo preg_replace("/--INA-- (\w+)/" , '<div class="wp"><b>2</b>$1</div>',$text);
```

https://3v4l.org/DdaFt

This assumes it's only one word after the ACT. If that is not correct then update your question with a more relevant example.

Comment: thanks but how to use in one line as i did in str_replace?

Comment: You can't, that is why I posted two lines. You have a trust issue. The replacements are not the same so I can't replace with the same html.  With active you want `1` with inactive `2` I can't make the code adapt for that.

Comment: ok sorry because problem i want in one line not two or ... i search for another method, thanks andreas

Comment: You can have one seriously messy line `Echo preg_replace("/--INA-- (\w+)/" , '<div class="wp"><b>2</b>$1</div>',preg_replace("/--ACT-- (\w+)/" , '<div class="wp"><b>1</b>$1</div>',$text));`

Comment: it is necessary to repeat preg_match? because this function has low speed and i don't want to repeat it twice..

Comment: @JohnJack _"because this function has low speed"_ - On strings of this size, I doubt you would ever notice any difference, unless you repeat the above code _many_ times per request.

Comment: To avoid chained execution you must surround the patterns with `.*` like `/.*--INA-- (\w+).*/`

Comment: @Theofanis chained execution? What do you mean? Doing that completely destroys the regex https://3v4l.org/v7BMU

Comment: @Andreas you have to specifically execute it two times resupplying the previous output to the second or else the output would be invalid like `--ACT-- active <div class="wp"><b>2</b>inactive</div>` or `<div class="wp"><b>1</b>active</div> --INA-- inactive`

Comment: @Theofanis - If you look at the code, it first replaces the ACT, then it uses that result and replaces INACT (that still haven't been replaced). You can also check the link that Andreas have added. Not sure what the objection is?

Comment: @Andreas tested and if it have two word after value won't work and the second word will be the outside of div test with this $text = '--ACT-- active user --INA-- inactive';

Comment: I know. From answer:  *This assumes it's only one word after the ACT. If that is not correct then update your question with a more relevant example.*

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will delete text between `--` and insert following text in your `<div>`:

```
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive';

$new_text = preg_replace(
    '/((--[A-Z]{3}--) (\w+))/',
    '<div class="wp"><b>1</b> ${3}</div>',
    $text
);

echo $new_text;
```

Comment: This is not valid. He is asking for a different output per parameter `<b>1</b>`, `<b>2</b>`

Comment: Oh well, sorry. This was my first regex, I'll try to get what you're looking for asap.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (not recommended) method with one call to preg_replace assuming no duplicates exist

```
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive';
$text = preg_replace('/ *--(\w+)-- */', '&$1=', trim($text)); // transform to url params
parse_str($text, $data);
var_dump($data);
/* Output
array(2) {
    ["ACT"]=>
  string(6) "active"
    ["INA"]=>
  string(8) "inactive"
}
*/
function format($data,$key,$transformation) {
    $parts = explode('%%', $transformation);
    return $parts[0].$data[$key].$parts[1];
}
echo format($data,'ACT','<div class="wp"><b>1</b>%%</div>');
//prints: <div class="wp"><b>1</b>active</div>
echo format($data,'INA','<div class="wp"><b>2</b>%%</div>');
//prints: <div class="wp"><b>2</b>inactive</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@JohnJack You can do it with `str_replace` by doing https://3v4l.org/lj6ct

```
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive user --EDI-- Banned user';
$text = str_replace(array('--ACT--','--INA--','--EDI--','%%'), array('<div class="wp"><b>1</b>','%%<div class="wp"><b>2</b>','%%<div class="wp"><b>3</b>','</div>'), $text.'%%');
print $text;
//prints: <div class="wp"><b>1</b> active </div><div class="wp"><b>2</b> inactive user </div><div class="wp"><b>3</b> Banned user</div>
```

It is terrible idea but it works.

Comment: @JohnJack Don't really know how to explain this. I just look at it and it seems wrong. But make sure there is no *%%* on the input or else you must change that last search term and the replacements accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution :

```
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive';
$textAfter= preg_replace('/--ACT-- +(\w+) +--INA-- +(\w+)/',
    '<div class="wp"><b>1</b>${1}</div> <div class="wp"><b>2</b>${2}</div>',
    $text);
echo $textAfter;
//prints: <div class="wp"><b>1</b>active</div> <div class="wp"><b>2</b>inactive</div>
```

A useful solution based on that would be :

```
function param($text, $name, $transformation) {
    return preg_replace("/.*$name +(\w+).*/",$transformation, $text);
}
$text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive';

echo param($text,'--ACT--','<div class="wp"><b>1</b>${1}</div>');
//prints: <div class="wp"><b>1</b>active</div>

echo param($text,'--INA--','<div class="wp"><b>2</b>${1}</div>');
//prints: <div class="wp"><b>2</b>inactive</div>
```

Comment: for the first one if i have three what should i write in preg_replace? "/--ACT-- +(\w+) +--INA-- +(\w+) +--EDI-- +(\w+)/" is correct?

Comment: @JohnJack Correct and change the replacement accordingly e.g.`$textAfter = preg_replace('/--ACT-- +(\w+) +--INA-- +(\w+) +--EDI-- +(\w+)/',
    '<div class="wp"><b>1</b>${1}</div> <div class="wp"><b>2</b>${2}</div> <div class="wp"><b>3</b>${3}</div>',
    $text);`

Comment: thanks but missed something and does not work, it work only if one word after value but if it is $text = '--ACT-- active  --INA-- inactive user'; not work? any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnJack replace `(\w+)` with `((\w+\s?)+)` so  `$textAfter = preg_replace('/--ACT-- +((\w+\s?)+) +--INA-- +((\w+\s?)+) +--EDI-- +((\w+\s?)+)/',
    '<div class="wp"><b>1</b>${1}</div> <div class="wp"><b>2</b>${3}</div> <div class="wp"><b>3</b>${6}</div>',
    $text);`

Comment: $text = '--ACT-- active --INA-- inactive user --EDI-- Banned user'; test with this and you will see that it does not work. what wrong?

Comment: @JohnJack sorry my mistake, change this part `<div class="wp"><b>3</b>${6}</div>` with this `<div class="wp"><b>3</b>${5}</div>` substitution params should increase by two starting from 1

Comment: thank you for all your reply's. yes this is what i already did and it works. but I still doing some research how to do it in this way str_replace(array('--ACT--','--INA--'), array('<div class="wp"><b>1</b></div>','<div class="wp"><b>2</b></div>'), $text); hope to find something because preg_replace is slow a little bit.. i want to use str_replace